# how to get png++ to work in windows visual studio

Tags: libpng

I get this error when compiling my code

```
Error   3   error C3861: 'strerror_r': identifier not found c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\png++\error.hpp  108 1   Depth-Estimation
```

I read at http://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?47990 it is because

```
In Visual Studio 2015 (14.0.25123.00 Update 2) the definition _STDC_LIB_EXT1_ is not set, meaning that in error.hpp it tries to fall back to strerror_r which isn't available anymore.

Because _STDC_LIB_EXT1_ is not set, _STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1_ is not defined, string.h is not included, and HAVE_STDERROR_S is not defined.
```

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in CodeBlocks.

You can change the line 108 that was:

```
return std::string(strerror_r(errnum, buf, ERRBUF_SIZE));
```

to

```
return std::string("");
```

While this should resolve the error and enable you to use png++ in your project, I'm guessing error reporting will no longer work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will never read this but hey, you never know.
Anyway, I just had the same problem, my fix:
Add

```
#define strerror_r(errno,buf,len) strerror_s(buf,len,errno)
```

Then change

```
return std::string(strerror_r(errnum, buf, ERRBUF_SIZE));
```

to

```
strerror_r(errnum, buf, ERRBUF_SIZE);
return std::string(buf);
```